# Program to convert WFN-file to Molden

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I have tried google but without success so here the question: does anybody know a tool that can covert WFN-file to Molden or to Molpro format (including orbital info not the coordinates only).

Comment: Which program do you use to get those wfn files?

Comment: ADF (indirectly via adf2aim), Gaussian

Comment: I found sth that does not convert wfn to molden but ADF output to molden. It is quite old (1999), but maybe it still works. [ADFrom](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/adf.html) There seems to be some attention from the programmer on building [a suite including adfrom](https://github.com/mariotti/freemol/tree/master/Freemol/programs/adfrom) but on Github it's the Fortran code, so you have to compile it and hope that it works.

Comment: I know this one and nope that will not work. This code is not supported by original programmer and is using a link to the libraries from SCM (i.e. ADF). These libraries have to be linked during compilation, however they are not working with any "relatively" current version of ADF. A year ago or so, I have even tried to contact the authors but they change a few times institutions they were working for and they do not use ADF anymore.

Comment: I am the author of ADFrom, and Kris is correct. I do not maintain anymore the ADFrom code. The main reason is that I am not using ADF since a while and I lost track for the updates. Indeed it needs ADF libraries for licensing reasons (I am not sure about today, I needed to read the binary output for some specific data). The code is in the suite ([freemol](https://github.com/mariotti/freemol)) for historical reasons and in case anybody wants to fork it ;)
But the full suite still compiles even on a mac!

Comment: sorry, but molden reads gaussian data, then saves it in molden format. or?

Answer (score 1):

When a wfn-file is loaded into Multiwfn and one tries to convert it into a molden file via `100 > 2 > 6`, it says `Error: This function works only when input file contains basis function information`.

So I guess, that as the wfn file lacks important information, it’s not easily possible to convert it into a molden file.